# Azure App Services access database issues when ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT set to Production

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, web-applications

App Services in Azure has a variable called ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT which if not present would be set to Production. It can be also added manually and set to Production. My application refuses to pull anything from database when that variable set to Production, however when it set to Development everything works.

I double checked an appsettings.json and appsettings.Development.json both pointing to the same database. Nothing in the code check for environment variables, all code related to that check is removed.

Error I get is "query returned no results" but as soon as environment set to Development, same query and same database returns all the results.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried by setting the configuration in startup.cs file? 
If not, please try the below option and see if it works for you.

Usually the way to get these settings from our ASP.NET Core is accessing to the injected environment variables. Hence we have to load these environment variables into our Configuration in the Startup.cs file:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

The order in which configuration sources are specified is also important, as this establishes the precedence with which settings will be applied if they exist in multiple locations.